# Creating react-native project with spesific version

Tags: react-native

I run `npx react-native init bilettm --version 0.59` this command in powershell.At the end of this process I can't create project.Because It gives me an annoying error like this `429 Too Many Requests - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/errorhandler`.I am a newcomer in react native.Anyone knows what I should do ?

Answer (score 0):

Above command is not working
from the current doc:

```
npx react-native@X.XX.X init AwesomeProject --version X.XX.X
```

You can create a project with 0.70 is

```
npx react-native@0.70 init AwesomeProject --version 0.70
```

Answer (score -1):

```
react-native init newproject --version react-native@0.59
```

try above command, Hope it works for you.

Comment: It gives me this error ` Invalid tag name "react-native@0.59.10": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.`